Can students effectively model the temperature effects of passic cooling on a scale architectural model?
I am helping some students made models for a Science fair. They'll make 1:12 scale (one-scale) models of these in sculpey and wood:

Roman court-houses with water features.
A Persian wind catcher.
Indian fountain cooling.

We will use a box fan to simulate wind and an infrared thermometer to examine temperature changes.

Though at scale, will miniature models will still demonstrate the cooling effects?

Would the decreased temperature be greater of lesser for the scale model relative to the real world architecture?


